# I am not allowed to log into my gmail account. Why not? is this a ubuntu thing, and how do I resolve it since there is no one to help

Tags: firefox, gmail

I am trying to log into my gmail account but am not being allowed to, says my pass word is incorrect (it is not ) and I'm told that I must have cookies enabled but Firefox (in Ubuntu) won't let me Why not? is this a ubuntu thing, and how do I resolve it since there is no one to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Gmail "thing", not an Ubuntu "thing". Try a different browser or a different device (like a phone). Cookies only helps the browser to remember the password next time you log in. The **correct** password should work every time. Check the CapsLock key and the keyboard layout. If you're using other language than default english as keyboard language, the keys may be mapped differently and you might be pressing the wrong keys (diacritics, symbols, etc).